# Test for difference between groups

Tags: regression

I have 3 groups: A,B,C. Each group presents only the number of observations for different condition. That means that group A=100, group B=80, group c=75. I want to check if the difference between the groups is significant - is it T-TEST to check it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

T-test is for two groups.  If you want to compare the means on some continuous variable across three groups, you need ANOVA or regression (they are equivalent).